# Why dependant picklist is not comming in the drop down?

Tags: dependent-picklist

I have a Custom picklist say `SubProcess`, which is dependent on the `SubStatus` field, even though I have included in the dependant picklist, but its not reflecting what could be the reason ?

I am getting error::

```
ERROR   
Error:
Sub-Process: bad value for restricted picklist field: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include your picklist values in your record type?